# Why Android normal layout folder always opens the screen in landscape mode

Tags: android, layout, landscape, portrait

I have divided my layout resources in Android project to many folders such asL
layout, layout-large, layout-normal-port-xhdpi-800x480, and so on.

The problem is when I click on xml file inside the (layout) folder which is the default folder it always opens in landscape; I tried to switch to portrait but it opens the xml file inside (layout-normal-port-xhdpi-800x480) folder.

How can I view the default layout as a portrait not landscape?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: try making folders as  layout, layout-large, layout-port-xhdpi-800x480 not sure

Comment: Actually I did, but no result

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the new layout qualifiers.

See here: [Support Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers)

layout-sw600dp  (7Inch Tablets)
layout-sw720dp  (10Inch Tablets)
etc.

They're all listed there.